# How to derive the distribution of OLS starting from the sample moments?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, method-of-moments

I know I am supposed to start from

$N^{1/2}[N^{-1}\sum x_{i}u_{i}]$

Then by central limit theorem that that it is asymptotically

$ N(E(x_{i}u_{i}),var(x_{i}u_{i})) $

and $E(x_{i}u_{i})=0$

so $ N(0,var(x_{i}u_{i})) $

from there I cant see how I get to the correct result which is supposed to be

$N(0,(E(x_{i}x'_{i}))^{-1}E(u^2_{i}x_{i}x'_{i})(E(x_{i}x'_{i}))^{-1})$

Comment: it looks like you have OLS with heteroskedastic error term so check out the well known paper by Halbert White whose title currently escapes me. I'll see if I can find the name of it.

Comment: The derivation is probably in here. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f9cc/e2ca192180e1a404a7577752a9c8ea8259ed.pdf

Comment: Here's another link that can probably lead to some good references. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors